# Not able to display the details page for a product in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On my products list page when i click on view icon underneath the product thumbnail it takes me to a blank product details page.[the product detail page has the right id but doesn't display anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpnxY.jpg)

This is my code for the product details page.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
const axios = require('axios');

const SingleProduct = () => {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const params = useParams();
useEffect(() => {

  fetchProduct();
 }, []);
 const fetchProduct = () => {


  axios
  .get(
      `http://localhost:5000/api/products/${params._id}`
    )
    .then((res) => {
      setData(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
      
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
;
};



return (
<div>
  {data.map((item) => {
    return (
      <div className='product-container' key={item._id}>
        <div>
          <img className='prod-image' src={item.imageUrl} alt='' />
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1 className='brand'>{item.name}</h1>
          <h2>{item.price}</h2>
          <p>{item.description}</p>
          <p>
            <strong>Price:</strong> {item._id}
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>Color:</strong> {item.color}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
);
;
}
export default SingleProduct;
```

This is the code in App.js:

```
<Route path='/SingleProduct/:_id' element={SingleProduct} />
```

This the code in the products list page:

```
import React from 'react'
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'




const ProductsPage = (props) => {
const items = props.items;
const getItems = props.getItems;

useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
  }, [])



    
  return (
    <>
    


    <section className="ProductsPage items-page" onload = {getItems}>
        
        {items.filter  (item => item.price < 1000).map(item => (
            
         <ul items-style>
            
              
                <img src={item.imageUrl} alt="product" />
                <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            
            <Link to={`/SingleProduct/${item._id}`}>View</Link> 
         </ul>
        //



        ))}
        
        
        
        
        </section>
        </>
)               }
                             

export default ProductsPage
```

Comment: Does it show anything on the console dev tool ?

Comment: No, it does not show anything on the console, do not why the single product page is not rendering.

Comment: Can you show react-dom code too? Maybe the link in react-router is incorrect

Comment: Added the code that you asked for

Comment: I don't think it go into the component. You can put console.log into `useEffect(() => { console.log("SingleProduct component is invoked", params 
fetchProduct();
 }, []);`. Then check is SingleProduct component is created in dev tool